# Use gif image in Javascript whilst waiting for data

Tags: javascript, jquery, gif, animated-gif

Whilst waiting for 'real-time' data from the server, I want to display a `gif` image. Otherwise the client sees nothing and doesn't know about the status of their request. With a gif image such as an 'egg-timer' for instance they would at least know that the request has been sent and client is now awaiting a response.

This is how I coded it:

```
  websocket.onmessage = function(data){
     while (!data){
     $("#display").append('/templates/image.gif');
     }
     CODE THAT IS EXECUTED ON RECEIPT OF data
    }
```

I'm using websockets for the communication protocol between client and server. But the `gif` image is not displayed whilst waiting for `data` from the server.

I'm a newbie to javascript so not sure what id wrong

EDIT

Thanks for the help, your suggestions got the gif image to work.

BUT the image I get is not a `gif` but what looks like a broken picture icon in (Chrome and nothing in Firefox). This is the code now:

```
$("#display").append('<img src="/templates/image.gif" />');
websocket.onmessage = function(data){
         CODE THAT IS EXECUTED ON RECEIPT OF data
}
```

The `gif` file is ok and in the right directory.

Thanks

Comment: I think that you want to display the gif as soon as the client has to start waiting (perhaps by some trigger like a click).  Your jQuery code is also wrong in that you want to append the image, not the source path, and you probably don't want to do that in a loop.  This loop will never be exited if data is false.

Comment: @ExplosionPills; yes you're right about: `....display(ing) the gif as soon as the client has to start waiting (perhaps by some trigger like a click)`. But I'm unsure how to execute this any other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be using:

```
$("#display").append('<img src="http://www.yourhost.com/templates/image.gif" />');
```

instead of:

```
$("#display").append('/templates/image.gif');
```

Alternatively you could also create a simple css class as follows:

```
.loading {
    display: block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background: transparent url('/templates/image.gif') no-repeat center center;
}
```

and then do :

```
$("#display").append('<span class="loading"></span>');
```

Answer (score 3):

Usually when I want to show a loading image, I will embed it directly in the HTML with display:none (or block if its supposed to show the loading image after page load while waiting for data).  Anytime I make a request for data I set the display to block prior to making the request so that there is no blocking, and then set the display back to none when the data arrives back.  I find it easier to control loading gifs via style sheets rather than adding them and removing them from the DOM.

Answer (score 2):

`onmessage` is only called when there actually is data so you don't have to loop waiting for it.

In general, you never want to loop waiting for data in javascript because that will block the actual event you are waiting for and because of javascript's single threaded nature you will both lock up the browser and never get your actual event.

I think you want something like this:

```
// show msg waiting for data
$("#display").append('/templates/image.gif');
websocket.onmessage = function(data){
     // CODE THAT IS EXECUTED ON RECEIPT OF data
     // remove or hide the temporary image here 
     // now that the data has arrived and been processed.
}
```